# rails api working in postman but not in angularjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I make a Rails API and now I try to access to that API using Postman everything is perfect and works fine

But AngularJS App in response to

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://ADDRESS/api/v1/sessions' from origin
'http://ADDRESS' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request
 doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Put something like the code below in `config/application.rb` of your Rails application. For example, this will allow GET, POST or OPTIONS requests from any origin on any resource.[reference](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors)

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # ...

    # Rails 5

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end

    # Rails 3/4

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The above mentioned configuration is same as in my rails application. But the error still occurs

Comment: post your config/application.rb file here